# How many characters is "New line" (\r\n) counted in SMSs?

Tags: jquery, sms

I am creating a text box for typing SMS. Which has 160 characters limitations.
As we know new line is counted as 2 characters in PC (windows): `\r\n`.

What is the policy for SMS senders. Is new line counted as two characters or one?

Shall I mention "Enter" as 2 characters for my JQuery character counter or one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMS internally is as well encoded as 0x0a and 0x0d, depending on \r and \n.
Note that is only, when regular character set is used, when you have special characters, text is encoded as UCS2, in that case \r\n takes 4 bytes.